# Transfer Avid project from one machine to another

Tags: software, avid

How can I transfer an Avid Media Composer project -- with all media -- from one computer to another?

Are there any issues with duplicating media when transferring media files?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet for transferring any type of media file will be to zip it along with any session files/data first to preserve the file types. Once you zip your files you can use any external hard drive to make the transfer from one machine to another.